# Unable to compile XeLaTeX after upgrading to TeXLive 2022

Tags: beamer, xetex, devanagari

I am on Debian Bookworm with TeXLive version `Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.6.21)`

I was able to compile an MWE with TeX Live 2021. But the same file doesn't get compiled after upgrading to TeX Live 2022 [which came along with Debian Bookworm]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{Shobhika Bold} 
\newfontfamily{\dev}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Shobhika} %
\newcommand{\devsize}{\Large}
\newcommand{\uvaca}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \begin{center}
            {\Huge  { \bfseries \dev।। puruṣottamayogaḥ ।।}}
        \end{center}    
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
            \begin{center}
                {\huge {\bfseries \dev  atha pañcadaśo'dhyāyaḥ}}            
            \end{center}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        {\dev {\devsize
        \hspace*{5em} {\uvaca śrībhagavānuvāca}%

        ūrdhvamūlamadhaḥśākhamaśvatthaṁ prāhuravyayam ।%

        chandāṁsi yasya parṇāni yastaṁ veda sa vedavit ।।1।।}}%
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}    
        {\dev {\devsize %
        adhaścordhvaṁ prasṛtāstasya śākhā 

        \hspace*{2em} guṇapravṛddhā viṣayapravālāḥ ।  

        adhaśca mūlānyanusantatāni

        \hspace*{2em} karmānubandhīni manuṣyaloke ।।2।।}}
     \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

**Error**

```
Runaway argument?
{\dev {\devsize adhaścordhvaṁ prasṛtāstasya śākhā 
! Paragraph ended before \beamer@inlineframetitle was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.44 ^^I \end{frame}
```

Interestingly, when I compile the same document as an article, it works.

Comment: If possible, I would suggest to switch from xelatex to lualatex. Xelatex can cause some problems with overlays etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz To learn another TeX language is beyond my time availability.

Comment: It is not another language, just another way to compile the same code.

Comment: Oh! Is it? Is there any additional syntax that I should learn?

Comment: There is no additional code, it is just an alterative to compiling with xelatex. There are some packages which only work in xelatex, but I don't see any of them in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer provided two ways to specify a frametitle:

- (my preferred) method via `\frametitle{...}`
- and `\begin{frame}{frametitle}`

If you use `{...}` as first thing on a frame, beamer thinks this is the frametitle. You can avoid this problem by adding an empty line after `\begin{frame}` or use `\begingroup ... \endgroup` instead of `{...}` (this should already have caused errors with TL2021 and earlier):

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{Shobhika Bold} 
\newfontfamily{\dev}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Shobhika} %
\newcommand{\devsize}{\Large}
\newcommand{\uvaca}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \begin{center}
            {\Huge  { \bfseries \dev।। puruṣottamayogaḥ ।।}}
        \end{center}    
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
            \begin{center}
                {\huge {\bfseries \dev  atha pañcadaśo'dhyāyaḥ}}            
            \end{center}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    
        {\dev {\devsize
        \hspace*{5em} {\uvaca śrībhagavānuvāca}%

        ūrdhvamūlamadhaḥśākhamaśvatthaṁ prāhuravyayam ।%

        chandāṁsi yasya parṇāni yastaṁ veda sa vedavit ।।1।।}}%
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}    
    
        {\dev {\devsize %
        adhaścordhvaṁ prasṛtāstasya śākhā 

        \hspace*{2em} guṇapravṛddhā viṣayapravālāḥ ।  

        adhaśca mūlānyanusantatāni

        \hspace*{2em} karmānubandhīni manuṣyaloke ।।2।।}}
     \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Compiles with TL2022: https://www.overleaf.com/read/cvxcvptgmzsv